# Assigning Values into Columns from JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I have some JSON like:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "2023-01-01",
            50,
            50,
            82,
            0.0,
            4.32,
            0.1,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-02",
            298,
            315,
            550,
            0.0,
            4.920634920634921,
            0.13758389261744966,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-03",
            709,
            724,
            1051,
            0.0,
            3.064917127071823,
            0.0930888575458392,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-04",
            264,
            292,
            660,
            0.0,
            6.493150684931507,
            0.2803030303030303,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-05",
            503,
            523,
            882,
            0.0,
            3.7667304015296366,
            0.14314115308151093,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-06",
            423,
            437,
            735,
            0.0,
            3.5652173913043477,
            0.12056737588652482,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-07",
            97,
            102,
            146,
            0.0,
            3.5294117647058822,
            0.13402061855670103,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-08",
            70,
            71,
            169,
            0.0,
            6.52112676056338,
            0.1,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-09",
            301,
            337,
            721,
            0.0,
            5.9614243323442135,
            0.26578073089701,
            0
        ],
        [
            "2023-01-10",
            313,
            352,
            678,
            0.0,
            5.8522727272727275,
            0.2364217252396166,
            0
        ]
    ],
    "meta": {
        "columns": [
            "timestamp__to_date",
            "visitors",
            "sessions",
            "page_views",
            "goal_conversion_rate",
            "events_per_session",
            "returning_visitors_rate",
            "goal_conversions"
        ],
        "count": 181
    }
}
```

How can I assign the values into correct columns, to get a result like so?

```
timestamp__to_date     visitors     sessions     page_views     goal_conversion_rate...
"2023-01-10"           313          352          678            0.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/). We will not write code to specification for you here. Plagiarism is a serious academic offense; aside from that, we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and analyze the task, identify the logical steps to solve the problem, and figure out *where you are actually stuck*. Make sure to check if the issue is already addressed in another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you decode your JSON string, you can simply build a dataframe using the `data` and `meta.columns` values:

```py
data = json.loads(jstr)
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['meta']['columns'])
```

Output:

```
  timestamp__to_date  visitors  sessions  page_views  goal_conversion_rate
0         2023-01-01        50        50          82                   0.0  \
1         2023-01-02       298       315         550                   0.0
2         2023-01-03       709       724        1051                   0.0
3         2023-01-04       264       292         660                   0.0
4         2023-01-05       503       523         882                   0.0
5         2023-01-06       423       437         735                   0.0
6         2023-01-07        97       102         146                   0.0
7         2023-01-08        70        71         169                   0.0
8         2023-01-09       301       337         721                   0.0
9         2023-01-10       313       352         678                   0.0

   events_per_session  returning_visitors_rate  goal_conversions
0            4.320000                 0.100000                 0
1            4.920635                 0.137584                 0
2            3.064917                 0.093089                 0
3            6.493151                 0.280303                 0
4            3.766730                 0.143141                 0
5            3.565217                 0.120567                 0
6            3.529412                 0.134021                 0
7            6.521127                 0.100000                 0
8            5.961424                 0.265781                 0
9            5.852273                 0.236422                 0
```